# trigger radio by clicking on div

Tags: jquery, html, css, recursion

Hi Friend I want when user click on a button then this code `<div class="row><input type="radio" name="radio"></div>"` will append to `body`.

Now the problem is div named `.row` is entire click-able I want when user click on the div then its children `<input type="radio" name="radio">` should be `trigger clicked`. But my code is not working as per my requirment its gives me errorr which shows in console that says `too much recursion`. I dont know what is this.

You can check my code here **http://jsfiddle.net/L9sezwge/** or you can check below

**SCRIPT**

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div class="row"><input type="radio" name="radio">dd</div>')
})
$(document).on('click','.row',function(e){

$('.row').removeClass('gray')
$(this).addClass('gray')
$(this).find('input').trigger('click')

})
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Click</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.row{padding:10px 40px; cursor:pointer;}
.row:hover{color:red;}
.gray{background:gray; color:red;}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L9sezwge/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cleanest way

The *cleanest* way is using `.prop('checked',true);` instead of `.trigger('click')`. In that way, no propagation will happen because no UI events are triggered.

```
$('button').click(function(){
     $('body').append('<div class="row"><input type="radio" name="radio">dd</div>');
});
$(document).on('click','.row',function(e){

     $('.row').removeClass('gray');
     $(this).addClass('gray');
     $(this).children('input').prop('checked',true); //Changed find() to children as well.

});
```

Check out this [**demo on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L9sezwge/7/).

Answer (score 4):

You need to stop event propagation from input radio else it will keep on triggering the div click event also. Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/L9sezwge/4/)

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div class="row"><input type="radio" name="radio">dd</div>')
})
$(document).on('click','.row',function(e){

$('.row').removeClass('gray');
$(this).addClass('gray');
$(this).find('input').trigger('click');

});

$(document).on('click','input:radio',function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // e.stopPropagation() is also ok, if you only want to prevent click on parent div 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or just another way. just wrap your radio input with label.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('body').append('<label class="row"><input type="radio" name="radio">dd</label>')
})
$(document).on('click', '.row', function(){
    $('.row').removeClass('gray');
    $(this).addClass('gray');
});
```

and make sure the label display is block

```
.row{display:block; padding:10px 40px; cursor:pointer;}
```